# Regex Javascript to extract a number not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am reading a long string in NodeJS JavaScript which will contain some key text with variations such as

Example 1:

```js
var s = `Line 1 Text 
Line 2 Text text text I would give a score of 2 out of 4 for this answer
Line 3 text`;
```

Example 2:

```
Line 1 Text 
Line 2 Text text text Score: 3 out of 4.
Line 3 text
```

Example 3:

```
Line 1 Text 
Line 2 Text text text the answer merits a score of 4 out of 4 blah blah 
Line 3 text
```

Example 4:

```
Line 1 Text 
Line 2 Text text text Score: 3/4.
Line 3 text
```

The length, number of lines, position of the score can vary.

In all cases I simply just want the score as a single number.

```js
var score_patt = await s
  .replace(/..*answer_mark.: (\d+|\d+\.\d+)[^\d]*.*/gis, "$1")
  .replace(/..* (\d+[\.\d]*) out of \d+[^\d]*.*/gis, "$1")
  .replace(/..* (\d+[\.\d]*) mark out of \d+[^\d]*.*/gis, "$1")
  .replace(/..* (\d+[\.\d]*) score out of \d+[^\d]*.*/gis, "$1")
  .replace(/..* Score: (\d+[\.\d]*)\/\d+[^\d]*.*/gis, "$1");

var ques_score = Number(score_patt);
```

In all cases I get ques_score = 0 returned.

Comment: There's absolutely no need for the `await` since there is no asynchronous code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main points here: You want `.match()` (instead of `.replace()`) and a regex better than those you are using.

```
(?<=Score:\s*)                         #                preceded by 'Score:' and any whitespaces,
\d+(?:\.\d+)?                          # Match a number
|                                      # or
\d+(?:\.\d+)?                          # a number
(?=(?: (?:score|mark)s?)? out of \d+)  # followed by 'scores out of', 'marks out of', etc.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9K0S9O/1).

The number you want will be stored in group 0:

```js
const match = s.match(regex);
const score = match[0];
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const testcases = [
  `Line 1 Text 
Line 2 Text text text I would give a score of 2 out of 4 for this answer
Line 3 text`,
  `Line 1 Text 
Line 2 Text text text Score: 3 out of 4.
Line 3 text`,
  `Line 1 Text 
Line 2 Text text text the answer merits a score of 4.5 out of 4 blah blah 
Line 3 text`,
  `Line 1 Text 
Line 2 Text text text Score: 3/4.
Line 3 text`
];

const regex = /(?<=Score:\s*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=(?: (?:score|mark)s?)? out of \d+)/;

for (const testcase of testcases) {
  const match = testcase.match(regex);
  const score = Number(match[0]);
  
  console.log(score);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```